# Sprite animation in eb guide (community ed)

Tags: animation

I want to create a sprite animation (similar to an hourglass). I found no way to do that, but there are script commands `f: animation_play`. How can I use this to show multiple pictures in a row (like a slideshow)? What do I have to pass as a parameter?

I searched the manual of guide studio and found only the script function, but not how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a slideshow (i.e. different images) by using an animated property:

1. Add an image widget to the view (here: "View 1" where the animation shall be shown. Name the image `Sprite`.
2. Add two properties to the image widget:

   - Type `Image list`, name it e.g. `sprite`
   - Type `Integer`, name it e.g. `spriteIdx`
3. Add the images to the resources of the model
4. Add the images to the image list `sprite`
5. Add an Animation widget to the image and add an `Animated property` to it:

   - Select "View 1" (not Data pool)
   - Choose `spriteIdx` which is below `Sprite`
6. Define the properties for the the animated property:

   - start = 0
   - end = number of pictures (not -1)
   - set duration, repeat, alternating as desired
7. To start the animation, you need a script:

   - add a property of type conditional script to the image `Sprite`
   - script source could be:

   ```
   function(v:arg0::bool)
   {
      if (!v:arg0)
      {
          f:trace_string("Play")
          f:animation_play(v:this->"Animation 1")
      }
      false
   }
   ```

   - the parameter of f:animation_play is the reference to the `Animated property` created in step 5
   - add a trigger event; alternatively you could e.g. start the animation when entering the state (with an `entry action`)