# EB Guide (com. ed 6.8) scripting engine reports "Expected 'Function () void' but got 'Error'

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to start an animation in eb guide using a script (state entry action). The scripting engine reports the error:

```
Expected 'Function () : void' but got 'Error'
```

How can I fix this?

The used script is:

```
function()
{
   f:animation_play(this->"View 1"->"Animation 1")
}
```

I try to get an animation similar to the one described in [Sprite animation in eb guide (community ed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773441/sprite-animation-in-eb-guide-community-ed), but it shall start when the state is entered.
Used version is eb guide 6.8 community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with the scripts:

1. Function returns wrong type:

   The scripting engine always takes the return value of the last command as return value of the function.

   In this case, f:animation_play does not get a valid parameter (see 2. below), which is interpreted as `Error` return value. In case the parameter would be correct, the return value would still be incorrect, because `animation_play` returns a boolean value (see EB GUIDE Studio manual). To return void, use the keyword `unit` as last line in the script.
2. State entry action tries to start animation

   A script which is executed when a state is entered or left cannot access children of the state, as they are not created yet (or already destroyed in case the state is left).

   To start the animation when entering the state, there are two possibilities (I suggest to use the first one):

   - Move the script to the animation widget (add a conditional script as user-defined property) with following code:

   ```
   {
    f:animation_play(v:this)
    false
   }
   ```

   Note the `false`keyword which ensures that a boolean value is returned. The script is automatically run once as soon as the current state is entered and all widgets are initialized.

   - Fire an event in the entry action script; another script can react on this event to start the animation. This is helpful if you don't want to directly start the animation but have some delay. Otherwise, the first approach is simpler.